# html5 pattern for first and last name

Tags: regex, html

I have a input box where the user can input the first name and last name. I have used html5 pattern for validation.

But the issue is when you put "Simon" then it's fine but if you write "Simon Simon" then it's not(Probably the problem is with the space between 2 words). I want the input box to allow both

1.Username

2.First and last name.

My code is

```
 <input id="login_input_username" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,64}" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_full_name" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="(this.value=='')? this.value='Firstname lastname':this.value;" value="Firstname lastname" required />
```

Comment: **[a-zA-Z ]{2,64}**.......... use this pattern. i hv added space after Z in ur pattern

Comment: Thanks but I tried with it.Unfortunately not working.

Comment: alos note that a name is not unique, you shouldn't use it as a login parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** What is a first name? Do you mean a given name? If so, please remember that only a part of the global population writes their family names as last names. You really should use the terms "given name" and "family name". Think about »Ai Weiwei« – the family name is »Ai«.

**2.** There are just too many options for names. `[a-zA-Z ]` does not even cover all North American or European names (think about »O'Doyle«). Family names may also contain a space character (as in »Mac Amhlaidh«). Staying with latin, what about French, Spanish or German names with accents or umlauts? And what about non-latin names? You know Владимир Путин?

**3.** You really should use two distinct input fields. **Do not use a regular expression on something that irregular** like a persons name.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this.It is really interesting.